# What does "spectremancer" mean?

Tags: meaning

I accidentally know this word while reading a manga in English.
I tried searching it on the Internet but nothing comes out.
Yet I found that maybe this word was originally "spectromancer" since there are no websites containing the word *spectremancer*
All of the information about *spectremancer* is little:

> "But there're others too, like that weird spectremancer."

I believe this word describes a type of person or an occupation.

[Source:  [MangaRock](https://mangarock.com/manga/mrs-serie-100080425/chapter/mrs-chapter-100429894) {Chapter 26, Page 8}]

Comment: Can you give us a link to the manga or the name of the book?

Comment: @Lordology Sure! it's "Tensei shitara ken deshita" chapter 26.1.
For short, here is the link to where the word is mentioned. 
(this word hasn't been mentioned anywhere prior to this chapter, so I have very little clue about it)
[link](http://l.mangatown.com/store/manga/25191/026.0/compressed/n009.jpg?token=a6396116fccfbf98a5e17c40c730399faf419a8a&ttl=1553950800)

Comment: Unfortunately, the link gives Error 401.  But it can be found on [MangaRock](https://mangarock.com/manga/mrs-serie-100080425/chapter/mrs-chapter-100429894) (page 8 of Chapter 26).  [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20il5.png) a picture of the strip.

Comment: You should probably add the link and/or the picture to your main post.

Comment: @Lordology sorry about that, but at that time i thought that was redundance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **spectre**: A ghost.
>
> **necromancer**: A person who practises necromancy; a wizard or magician.
>
> **necromancy**: The supposed practice of communicating with the dead, especially in order to predict the future.
>
> **necro-**: Relating to a corpse or death.
>
> **-mancy**: Divination by a specified means.
>
> **divination**: The practice of seeking knowledge of the future or the unknown by supernatural means.

All can be found on https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/

Thus, by analogy, we have (I made this up):

> **spectremancer**: A person who practises seeking knowledge of the future or the unknown by means of communication with a ghost.

Perhaps spectremancer is indeed a 'better' word than spectromancer, because spectro- represents spectrum (eg, spectrochemistry). However, people also use spectro- for ghosts:

> [Spectrophilia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrophilia) is sexual attraction to ghosts [...]

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed explanation. But if that is, spectremancer is not so different from necromancer, isn't it? Maybe necromancers let the spirits get into them while spectremancers summon it and have conversation with them instead?